# Maven & Eclipse remote debugging: connection refused

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven, remote-debugging

I'm trying to do remote debugging with Maven and Eclipse. On the remote machine, I do `mvnDebug spring-boot:run`, and on the local machine in Eclipse, I set up a *Remote Java Application* debug configuration with the appropriate host IP and port and Connection Type as *Standard (Socket Attach)*.

On the remote machine, before attempting to connect with Eclipse, I only see:

```
Preparing to execute Maven in debug mode
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

`ss -aln` shows something listening on port 8000: `users:(("java",pid=949917,fd=4))`. As soon as I start the debug process in Eclipse on the local machine, the regular Maven output appears on the remote machine:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (NON-CANONICAL_2019-11-27T20:26:29Z_root)                                                 
Maven home: /opt/maven                                                                                       
Java version: 1.8.0_242, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre                
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8                                                              
OS name: "linux", version: "5.5.8-arch1-1", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"                                    
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
```

so apparently a connection is made. The output from Maven is identical to a regular run. But Eclipse displays `Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.` with no additional information, and by now nothing is listening on port 8000 on the remote machine anymore.

I don't have any idea how to even debug this, and the config couldn't be simpler.

The contents of the `mvnDebug` script are:

```
MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000"

echo Preparing to execute Maven in debug mode

env MAVEN_OPTS="$MAVEN_OPTS" MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS="$MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS" "`dirname "$0"`/mvn" "$@"
```

Any suggestions or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your problem is that `springboot:run` fork the process, like maven surefire does: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html 
My guess is that unlike surefire, `springboot:run` let maven finish. This would explain why you can't connect with Eclipse. `mvnDebug` is mainly for debugging maven and plugins, rather than your own application.

Comment: Well I did seemingly nothing but apparently I'm able to connect now. Eclipse SNAFU I guess. There's no `connection refused` error, and the Debug view shows a running *Remote Java Application* thread, But breakpoints seem not to be effective.

Comment: @NoDataFound The config in the link solves my problem. Paste it in an answer if you want.

Comment: Yup. I created an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like maven-surefire-plugin with forked test, springboot seems to fork to a new jvm process.  Hence, `mvnDebug` won't help you in that case: to debug your springboot instance from Maven, you must set up appropraite jvmArguments per this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <configuration>
      <jvmArguments>
        -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
      </jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
    ...
  </plugin>
```

While I can not explain why you can't connect using remote debug, my hint is that Spring Boot let maven terminates. I did not test but this would explain why you can't connect with Eclipse.

Note that `mvnDebug` is mainly for debugging maven and plugins, rather than your own application.

Answer (score -1):

The run config you tried is for java 4 and below.

for java 5 and above try to use for MAVEN_OPTS:

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000

Comment: The `mvnDebug` is something that ships with maven and ... it works with maven 3.6.x + Java 8 (tested it ... this year :))